# Using default object construction with JsonContract

Tags: c#, json.net

When you are deserializing objects with constructor parameters, the default serializer is able to use `null` for some of them. However, if you want to create an object via a `JsonContract` and calling `DefaultCreator` you'll get a `NullReferenceException`.

Is there a way I can use the same instantiation logic for types that I resolved with `ResolveContract(..)`? I'd like to avoid adding parameterless constructors to all affected types that I'm using.

This means, I'd like my custom converter to be able to initialize objects by injecting `null`s for constructor parameters that are not specified like the first call to `DeserializeObject` does, that does not use the custom converter.

---

I've created this small proof-of-concept demo to show you what I mean:

```
void Main()
{
    var json = @"
    {
        'User': {
            'Age': 80
        }

    }";

    // Works
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PC>(json).Dump();

    // Does not work unless you uncomment the parameterless constructor
    // or add a `Name` property to the above json.
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PC>(json, new UserConverter()).Dump();
}

public class PC
{
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public User(string name) { }

    //public User() {}

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

My custom converter that I use to resolve the type is implemented like this:

```
public class UserConverter : JsonConverter<User>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, User value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // I don't need it so it's not implemented.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override User ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, User existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jToken = JToken.Load(reader);
        existingValue = existingValue ?? (User)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator();
        serializer.Populate(jToken.CreateReader(), existingValue);
        return existingValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Json.NET can use constructors. The classes don't match the JSON string though. If the `User` constructor was `public User(int age) { Age=age;}` you'd get back a properly initialized object

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm afraid you might have missed the point of my question ;-(

Comment: Which is? `In my actual use-case` what *is* the actual case? What `$type` property?  There's no such property in the code you used and the example demostrates a typo, not an actual problem Post a *relevant* code example

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're still missing the point... the point is to create an object with constructor parameters by using the same logic as the first call to the `Deserialize` method does (without the custom converter), which is to inject `null`s for missing arguments. I've removed the paragraph that has absolutely nothing to do with this issue... it turns out to be too distracting.

Comment: Post a Minimal Complete Verifiable example, don't force people to fix the code to make it run

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it does demonstrate the issue and it's a complete exmaple that behaves exactly as desired.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the `Age` is not `0`, it's initialized to `80` and yes, `name` should be ignored and be `null` (which is exactly how the first example behaves) - I want the custom converter to do the same instead of throwing an exception. I appreciate your help but I have the feeling that you don't seem to understand how `json.net` handles it :(

Comment: I will put this miss understanding on the Tag C# and Json that only see a valid question once a day. I do think that the question is good, and has a MCVE. With no surprise for a CR user.

Comment: @xdtTransform could you clarify your point? How is this question not good? It has everything in it that both demonstrates the issue and the expected/unexpected behaviour. I don't know what I could post more :-|

Comment: @T3ch, I said Good. Miss understanding. Sorry for the poor English. You produced a MCVE. And the question is clear. Must have miss typed something.

Comment: @xdtTransform oh, I'm sorry, indeed you did, I somehow _injected_ the _not_ there :-]